# Primary key error when running in C# but not SSMS

Tags: stored-procedures, ssms

I have written a stored procedure to insert a record into a table that is used with our ERP system.  When a record is written to this table there are triggers on the table that were written by the company we purchased the ERP system from.

When I run the stored procedure I wrote from SSMS the data gets added without any errors.  When I run the C# code I wrote for an ASP.NET app to call that stored procedure I get an error that I can't add a record with a duplicate primary key.

Any ideas on why I'm not getting an error when running the stored procedure from SSMS I get no errors, but when I call the stored procedure from C# and trying to insert the same data I'm getting a primary key error?  I've deleted the record that I added in SSMS and I've verified that the primary key doesn't exist, but I still get the error in my C# code.

Below is the stored procedure I wrote:

```
/*
declare @Site       nvarchar(8),
    @BatchDef   ApsBatchType,
    @WagonNo    int,
    @Infobar    InfobarType 
exec TM_CreatePaintBatchSp 'WI_Plt2','18B84-Paint_S',5,@Infobar OUTPUT
*/

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TM_CreatePaintBatchSp]
@Site       nvarchar(8),
@BatchDef   ApsBatchType,
@WagonNo    int,
@Infobar    InfobarType = null OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
--SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CustOrderNo    nvarchar(6) = SUBSTRING(@BatchDef,1,6),
        @SpoolNo        nvarchar(5),
        @Job            JobType,
        @Suffix         SuffixType,
        @OperNum        OperNumType,
        @BatchedProdId  ApsBatchNumberType 

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    EXEC SetSiteSp @Site,null;

    EXEC GetBatchedProdSp @BatchedProdId OUTPUT

    INSERT production_batch
    (prod_batch_id, batch_definition_id, batch_job, batch_suffix, [status], Uf_WagonNo)
    VALUES (@BatchedProdId, @BatchDef, ' ', '0', 'A', @WagonNo)

    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    SET @Infobar = ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    RETURN
END CATCH
END
```

ApsBatchType is data type nvarchar(30)

And the primary key is `prod_batch_id`. The call to SP GetBatchedProdSp gets the next available number to use for the INSERT

Below is the C# code:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        string infobar = "";

        Conn.Open();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("TM_CreatePaintBatchSp", Conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site", "WI_Plt2");
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchDef", txtBatchDef.Text);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WagonNo", Convert.ToInt16(wddWagonList.SelectedValue));
            comm.Parameters.Add("@Infobar", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2800);
            comm.Parameters["@Infobar"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters["@Infobar"].Value = null;

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            infobar = comm.Parameters["@Infobar"].Value is DBNull ? default(string) : (string)comm.Parameters["@Infobar"].Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(infobar))
            {
                DialogMessage.Text = infobar;
                ModalWebDialogWindow.Header.CaptionText = "Error";
                ModalWebDialogWindow.WindowState = Infragistics.Web.UI.LayoutControls.DialogWindowState.Normal;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException SqlEx)
        {
            DialogMessage.Text = SqlEx.Message;
            ModalWebDialogWindow.WindowState = Infragistics.Web.UI.LayoutControls.DialogWindowState.Normal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DialogMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            ModalWebDialogWindow.WindowState = Infragistics.Web.UI.LayoutControls.DialogWindowState.Normal;
        }
        finally
        {
            Conn.Close();
            Conn.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: I've added my code to my original question.

Comment: ApsBatchType is data type nvarchar(30).  PK is prod_batch_id.  The call to SP GetBatchedProdSp gets the next available number to use for the INSERT.

Comment: Depends the value returned by `EXEC GetBatchedProdSp`  of the parameters that you pass to the SP?

Comment: Make sure your connection string in the app matches SSMS. Almost every time code works in SSMS but not in C# it’s because the app is either pointed at the wrong database/server or is using an instance on demand (check for attacheDbFileName).